# Cygwin : typing characters can't display after popup browser

Tags: cygwin

I want to run activator from play framework(www.playframework.com). 
When i type activator, the program will run and popup browser. When i closed or hided the browser, I continue to use cygwin bash for other commands.

But when i try to type, i can't see the characters\text\command that i'm typing. When i hit enter, i can see the bash response output to what i've typed.
I also try to re-install and it gave the same problem.

What could be the problem? do i miss some setting? i'm using win8.1 pro 64bit and install latest cygwin with default selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same issue with the following configuration:

- Cygwin on Window 7 64 Professional
- Typesafe Activator 1.2.3
- Oracle JDK 1.7 64

So, this is how I've managed to solve this problem, and so far I didn't noticed any collateral effects:

**Edit "activator" shell script:**

```
[PATH_TO_YOUR_INSTALLATION]\activator-1.2.3\activator
```

Comment the following line (around #220) from:

```
    # stty -icanon min 1 -echo > /dev/null 2>&1
```

**Another option**

If don't want to edit this file, just run (blindly) the follow command, and echo start working again:

```
stty icanon echo
```

That's it!

Comment: Thanks. man... u r life saver... i've suspected this too and asked play fw grp... not response from them yet perhaps ..

Comment: You're welcome! Since I've been struggling with that issue too, I'm very glad to share! If you get any official or more elegant solution, please let me know!